# Using .NET Task.WhenAll when some of the tasks are not started right away

Tags: .net, multithreading, async-await

I have a list of jobs that I would like to execute in parallel, but some of them can only start when others are completed. For exampe: job A and B can start right away, job C can start when A is done, job D can start when both A and B are done. I don't know exact order beforehand, because it comes from configuration.

I hoped I could create all the tasks, start some of them, then when each one finishes, check if I can start others. Simplified code would look something like this:

```
    public class Job { }
    List<Job> _jobsList; 
    List<Task> _taskList;

    private async Task RunJobs()
    {
        foreach (var job in _jobsList)
        {
            _taskList.Add(new Task(async () => await RunJob(job)));
        }
        StartJobs();
        await Task.WhenAll(_taskList);
    }

    private void StartJobs()
    {
        foreach (var task in _taskList)
        {
            //some logic here to determine which jobs can start now
            if (canstart)
            {
                task.Start();
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task RunJob(Job job) 
    {
        //await some async processing
        StartJobs(); //to start other jobs depending on this one
    }
```

This doesn't work unfortunatelly - Task.WhenAll is done while some of the tasks are still running. The problem if I understand it correctly is because Task constructor doesn't work properly with async methods, and I have to use Task.Run instead. All workarounds I can think of are rather complicated. Is there a way to achieve this simply somehow?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That code is working as expected.

There is no constructor of `Task` or `Task<T>` that takes a `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<TResult>>`, so you're using `Task(Action)` which completes as soon as the code returns from the action.

There's almost no reason to ever use the constructor of `Task` or `Task<T>`. In fact, [the remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor):

> ## Remarks
>
> This constructor should only be used in advanced scenarios where it is required that the creation and starting of the task is separated.
>
> Rather than calling this constructor, the most common way to instantiate a Task object and launch a task is by calling the static Task.Run(Action) or TaskFactory.StartNew(Action) method.
>
> If a task with no action is needed just for the consumer of an API to have something to await, a TaskCompletionSource should be used.

A none of that is needed in this case.

Try this:

```cs
private Task RunJobs()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    var taskList = new Task[_jobsList.Count];
    for (var j = 0; j < _jobsList.Count; j++)
    {
        var job = _jobsList[j];
        taskList[j] = tcs.Task.ContinueWith(_ => RunJob(job));
    }
    
    tcs.SetResult(true);
    return Task.WhenAll(taskList);
}
```

Comment: My code doesn't work because RunJob method has await line inside, and Task.WhenAll seem not to be waiting for this inside await. I could expand my example if needed.

Comment: Also, as I explained, all of my jobs cannot be started at once, so I cannot use RunJob right away as you suggest.

Comment: What do you think happens when you use `new Task(async () => await RunJob(job))`? Check the linked docs.

Comment: If I create tasks like this: _taskList.Add(new Task(async () => await RunJob(job))); they are not started untill I specifically call task.Start() (in StartJobs method). In your example: _taskList.Add(RunJob(job)) jobs are run immediately - which is not what I want

Comment: @Taras, based on that, I've updated the code sample.

Comment: Your code sample still doesn't work the way I need - jobs are still executed all at once. However, using the TaskCompletionSource class I was able to produce a working solution, the key was to create a separate TaskCompletionSource for each job and then just run jobs directly and then SetResult when each finishes, no ContinueWith is needed. Anyway, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Taras, you need the jobs to run sequencially?